# iOS internationalization with downloaded images

Tags: ios, internationalization

I am building a internationalized app on iOS, where the app suppose to download a few images from the server (say 01.png, 02.png, 03.png, 04.png, where 01 and 03 are the English version of 2 images, and 02 and 04 are the Chinese version of 2 images). 
I know how to set internationalization locally (naming both files to the same name, and put one to en.lproj folder and the other one to zh-Hant.lproj folder).

I'm just wondering is there a better way to do this programatically?

or I'll have to programatically download from server -> put files in their language dependend server-> rename ?

P.S. I do not have control of the server, so renaming files from server will not be an option. those image files are shared between iOS and Android devices. (I know Android append language and resolution specific text to the file name)

Comment: Better way than what? Yes you will need to download and define some naming / location scheme.

Comment: I'm just wondering where would be the best place to store the downloaded file. Because from my understanding, mainBundle is not an option. However, I do have some files that were stored in mainBundle when the user first install the app, and the app programatically load files and display on screen. If some files were stored in mainBundle and some files were stored in sharedFolder, would my program recognise both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manage the download and usage of these files yourself. The standard localisation system is based upon resources which are part of the main bundle. You (broadly speaking) have 2 options:

1. Download the individual files, name them and store them in the cache folder (probably not the documents folder as this content doesn't need to be backed up), load them yourself as required by referring to the appropriate name.
2. Download a prepared bundle which contains the strings and images you want to use for the localised app. Use a combination of `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` and a custom implementation similar to `imageNamed:` (throughout your app) so you can obtain resources from the specified bundle.

You need to mediate between content in the main bundle and your additional storage.